# Error when extracting values from a rasterBrick or rasterStack

Tags: r, r-raster

I am having trouble extracting values or a point from a multi band raster of class `rasterStack` or `rasterBrick`. 'extract' works well with the individual rasters but posts an error when applied to the `rasterStack` or `brick`.

```
> all.var
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 89, 180, 16020, 34  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 2, 2  (x, y)
extent      : -179, 181, -89, 89  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       :    period_max, pct_signif_periodmax, pct_coi_periodmax,    pct_ispos_signif, events_pos_periodmax, events_neg_periodmax, events_pos_all, events_neg_all,  maxpower_pos,  maxpower_neg, maxpower_events_pos, maxpower_events_neg, maxpower_pos_norm, maxpower_neg_norm, maxpower_events_pos_norm, ... 

> point
Lon      Lat
1  166.2790 -10.2690
2   26.9000 -33.6000
3  153.6209 -28.7001
4  113.8333 -28.6833
5  153.6335 -28.6591
6  153.5836 -28.4643
7   32.6833 -27.5333
8   32.6880 -27.5260
9   32.6880 -27.5260
10  32.6880 -27.5260


> point.extract<-extract(all.var, point, buffer=50000,na.rm=TRUE,fun=mean)
Error in apply(x, 2, fun2) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

This works with individual rasters but fails with stack/brick and elicits an error only when  I use a buffer argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working R example that illustrates the error:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(nrow=89, ncol=180, nl=34, xmn=-179, xmx=181, ymn=-89, ymx=89, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
b[] <- 1

p <- matrix(c(166.2790,-10.2690,26.9000,-33.6000,153.6209,-28.7001,113.8333,-28.6833,153.6335,-28.6591,153.5836,-28.4643,32.6833,-27.5333,32.6880,-27.5260,32.6880,-27.5260,32.6880,-27.5260), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

v <- extract(b, p, buffer=50000, na.rm=TRUE, fun=mean)
```

That indeed gives the error you reported, probably due a bug in the raster package. Here is a work-around:

```
v <- extract(b, p, buffer=15000000)
# get the mean for each point (buffer) by layer
vv <- lapply(v, function(x) ifelse(is.matrix(x), colMeans(x, na.rm=TRUE), x))
# combine
do.call(rbind, vv)
```

Comment: Roger that. This work around works great. However, the output  (i.e. v) is a vector as opposed to a dataframe/matrix of 34 columns representing each layer. Am i missing something?

Comment: This gives you the mean for each point (hence the vector is length 10). To get the mean for each layer, you could do `rowMeans(do.call(cbind, v))`

Comment: not quite. this gets the global row means. Ideally the output should be a matrix of 10 rows (xy coordinates) and 34 columns (layers) dimension

Comment: this does not get the average (i.e. fun=mean in the original code) of the values extracted for each point and layer across the buffer..

Comment: ....for instance if you increase the buffer size in the example above to say 150000m, the row dimensions are not 10

Comment: My layers have lots of na's and will need to adjust the buffer until I have no more NA's i the matrix

Comment: both in the answer above and in my data, the line with `lapply` gives an error: Error in base::colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: it works with large buffers (when you have a matrix in each list element). Your function in lapply could test for that

Comment: for example with the above if I set the buffer to 150k or even 200k it doesn't work. I appreciate your help anyways

Comment: this works with the data above but doesn't seem to work with my rasterStack which has lots of NA's. returns 'dimensions' error above

Comment: I think it is failing because some rows have all NA's..hence the 'at least two dimensions' error. If there is a way to return NA and not attempt to 'lapply' such rows..it may solve the problem

Comment: I have added an `ifelse` to the lapply to only do a colMeans when you have a matrix (two dimensions)

Comment: This doesnt return the dimension error, however if I do `matrix(vv)` the dimension of the matrix has one column..and if I run the entire code, a vector with length equal to my `nrows` is returned

Comment: Joe, did you ever find a working answer to this? I am having precisely the same problem, and would love to know what you ended up doing!

Comment: Leah, The example I provided works OK with the current version of raster. Are you using the current version (2.8-4)?