# Converting a list of data frames to a single data frame and change column names

Tags: r, list, dplyr

My data is presented below using `dput`.

```
dat <- structure(list(`60` = structure(c(25.2142857142857, 25.2142857142857, 
25.2142857142857, 16.8333333333333, 6.18181818181818, 6.45454545454545, 
39.3076923076923, 17.8, 30.2307692307692, 31.9090909090909, 338.872342659885, 
338.872342659885, 338.872342659885, 312.566239187662, 108.98770426029, 
132.000329498368, 295.499325777881, 289.05210119046, 279.319320138619, 
282.696361655751), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("CanCov", "Aspect"))), `100` = structure(c(22.2285714285714, 
21.8285714285714, 22.2285714285714, 17.4285714285714, 7.54054054054054, 
5.51351351351351, 32.8823529411765, 18.0285714285714, 31.3125, 
32.5833333333333, 328.300126247896, 336.611388179775, 328.300126247896, 
288.830157290819, 132.674633942446, 122.597267778504, 295.162359106757, 
254.508961455896, 280.326744650874, 287.386617538886), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("CanCov", "Aspect"))), `500` = structure(c(10.786941580756, 
10.7688787185355, 10.8489702517162, 10.7628278221209, 14.1569301260023, 
12.9438717067583, 12.8735632183908, 10.8551724137931, 20.729667812142, 
23.3722794959908, 195.270942450807, 195.540990751048, 195.662725661548, 
190.688980052674, 165.038240066186, 133.772446928244, 198.45485951978, 
188.942107644257, 203.862336021767, 217.567077176237), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("CanCov", "Aspect"))), `1000` = structure(c(10.3804067602406, 
10.3746059042706, 10.381156930126, 9.8993981083405, 13.26243567753, 
13.6912732474964, 11.3125, 9.73461208130547, 17.5430539609644, 
18.8537492844877, 174.841410186063, 174.803449739022, 174.777413321887, 
169.181037352303, 148.07213983955, 145.460198642085, 157.562633627451, 
162.484978829108, 159.688505118645, 163.433969343022), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("CanCov", "Aspect")))), .Names = c("60", 
"100", "500", "1000"))
```

I have a list with four elements (named 60, 100, 500, and 1000).

```
> str(dat)
List of 4
 $ 60  : num [1:10, 1:2] 25.21 25.21 25.21 16.83 6.18 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "CanCov" "Aspect"
 $ 100 : num [1:10, 1:2] 22.23 21.83 22.23 17.43 7.54 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "CanCov" "Aspect"
 $ 500 : num [1:10, 1:2] 10.8 10.8 10.8 10.8 14.2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "CanCov" "Aspect"
 $ 1000: num [1:10, 1:2] 10.4 10.4 10.4 9.9 13.3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "CanCov" "Aspect"
```

I want to make a single 8 by 10 data frame where the columns correspond to the list name.  Specifically, the columns would be labeled CanCov_60, Aspect_60, CanCov_100, ... ,CanCov_1000, Aspect_1000, where the values for CanCov_60 and Aspect_60 would come from the list with the corresponding name.

I suspect `ldply` is the best function to use but cannot seem to connect the dots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in base-R, by using lapply on your *list names*. First, we retrieve that specific dataframe, then we change the column names and return it. Finally, we use `do.call(cbind(...))` to create the result.

Edit: I went by the title of the question and assumed all objects were dataframes and didnt check. However, they were in fact matrices, as @Damianofantini pointed out. I've added a conversion to data.frame.

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(names(dat),function(x){
  res <- dat[[x]]
  colnames(res) <- paste(colnames(res),x,sep="_")
  data.frame(res)
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `doParallel` version that can be parallelized:

```
library(doParallel)
foreach(i = seq_along(dat), .combine = cbind) %do% {
  x <- dat[[i]]
  colnames(x) <- paste(colnames(x), names(dat)[i], sep = "_")
  x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is very similar to Heroka's approach, however, I believe it will be a tad faster.  This is because `dplyr::bind_cols` [is considerably faster](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/01/09/dplyr-0-4-0/) than the `do.call(cbind())` approach.  Unfortunately, to use `dplyr::bind_cols` it is necessary that all elements within the list are `data.frame`s.  I therefore need to adopt a `Map` (i.e.`mapply`) strategy which both converts the matrices to `data.frame` and changes the variable names.

```
library(dplyr)

res <- Map(function(x, y){colnames(x) = paste(colnames(x), y, sep = "_"); as.data.frame(x)}, x = dat, y = names(dat)) %>%
  bind_cols(.)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could loop through your list and copy each matrix in a recipient matrix, rename the column names on the fly (as you specified) and then just convert your recipient matrix in a data frame.
It won't be as fast as using apply, but you should get the job done (if your list is tiny).

```
new_dat<-matrix(nrow=10, ncol =0)

for (i in 1:length(dat)){
  colnames(dat[[i]]) <- paste(colnames(dat[[i]]), "_", names(dat)[i], sep='')
  new_dat<-cbind(new_dat,dat[[i]])  
}
new_dat<- data.frame(new_dat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(new_dat)
```

Comment: Explain what you changed.

Comment: You are right that this will get the job done, but for-loops and especially growing objects in them is not a good habit to get into. Same for unnecessary converting of dataframes to matrices and back.

Comment: 1- Heroka, your solution is kinda elegant, thank you.. I learned something today. 2- The list contains matrices, I am converting a matrix to data frame only at the end. 3- Funny fact. The requirement was to produce a data frame and all your codes return matrix-class objects! My code is the only one returning a data.frame and still I got a minus 1... lol.

Comment: @DamianoFantini I'm sorry, you're right about the datatype. I assumed that they were dataframes as indicated by the title of the post, didn't check/see it that they weren't. Have edited the answer with a shoutout to you :)