# Create a loop to extract data from multiple raster

Tags: r, loops, extract, raster

I have 8 rasters that I tired stacking and extracting data from using a set of points.  But It didn't work out because rasters have a different extent.

I am really bad at creating loops. How would a write a loop function in R studio where I could loop the extract function and extract data from each raster and export data to a table. Below is my current script.

```
  H1 <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "Shapefile")
  L1= raster('raster.tiff')
  L2= raster('raster.tiff')
  L3= raster('raster.tiff')
  L4= raster('raster.tiff')
  L5= raster('raster.tiff')
  L6= raster('raster.tiff')
  L7= raster('raster.tiff')
  L8= raster('raster.tiff')

   files<- list()
   files[[1]] <- L1
   files[[2]] <- L2
   files[[3]] <- L3
   files[[4]] <- L4
   files[[5]] <- L5
   files[[6]] <- L6
   files[[7]] <- L7
   files[[8]] <- L8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the function `raster::extract`. Also, your example is not complete, so I cannot provide a complete solution.

Also, I'm assuming that you have a set of points you want to extract defined as a matrix called `coord`.

If my assumtions are correct, you can use

```
d <- lapply(files, extract, y = coord)
```

The third argument is forwarded to `extract`, so you're effectively looping

```
extract(files[[1]], y = coord)
extract(files[[2]], y = coord)
...
```

You get a list with one element per element in `files`. Then you need to merge them together, for example with

```
library(dplyr)
output <- bind_rows(d, .id = "raster")
```

Comment: Not sure if these should be a separate question but in there a way to keep the file names for each raster as the header when you extract data. ( i.e keep L1.L2.L3 etc in the header of the files?

Comment: I don't fully understand. If you used the function `dplyr::bind_rows(..., .id = "raster")`, the values `L1`, `L2`, etc. should appear in a column called `raster`.

Comment: If you post a new question, it helps a lot to create a [mcve] in your question. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619218/extract-raster-values-from-stack-to-points-in-for-loop?rq=1) how to create example `raster()` so that others can actually run your code on their machines.

Comment: Also, if `lapply` is a new function for you, I would strongly recommend that you set some time aside just for the purpose of learning R, instead of learning it as you code. For example using Datacamp. The money is well spent, as it pays off in that you are much faster and have more trust that your results are correct. (I'm not related to Datacamp, this is based on the experience of a colleague)